# Python tkinter checkboxes always returning value as 0 even when they are checked

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

It's supposed to be a GUI pizza order form so it has more but the problem that i'm encountering is when it gets the a variable that is supposed to be oliveSelection it always returns as 0 when checked and not 1.

```
from tkinter import *
myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("800x600")
myGui.title("Pete's Pizza Parlour~Order Form")


TOPPING SELECTION
    toppings_lbl=Label(myGui,text="Toppings:",font=("Good Times",10),fg="blue").pack()
    a=IntVar()
    olives_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Olives",variable=a).pack()
    b=IntVar()
    tomatoes_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Tomatoes",variable=b).pack()
    c=IntVar()
    pepperoni_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Pepperoni",variable=c).pack()
    d=IntVar()
    hotPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Hot Peppers",variable=d).pack()
    e=IntVar()
    onions_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Onions",variable=e).pack()
    f=IntVar()
    ham_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Ham",variable=f).pack()
    g=IntVar()
    sausage_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Sausage",variable=g).pack()
    h=IntVar()
    greenPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Green Peppers",variable=h).pack()

olivesSelection=a.get()
tomatoesSelection=b.get()
pepperoniSelection=c.get()
hotPeppersSelection=d.get()
onionsSelection=e.get()
hamSelection=f.get()
sausageSelection=g.get()
greenPeppersSelection=h.get()

olivesSelectionStr="olives"
tomatoesSelectionStr="tomatoes"
pepperoniSelectionStr="pepperoni"
hotPeppersSelectionStr="hot peppers"
onionsSelectionStr="onions"
hamSelectionStr="ham"
sausageSelectionStr="sausage"
greenPeppersSelectionStr="green peppers"
noToppingsStr="no toppings."
def checkToppings():
    toppingsList=""
    if(olivesSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+olivesSelectionStr
    elif(tomatoesSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+tomatoesSelectionStr
    elif(pepperoniSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+pepperoniSelectionStr
    elif(hotPeppersSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+hotPeppersSelectionStr
    elif(onionsSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+onionsSelectionStr
    elif(hamSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+hamSelectionStr
    elif(sausageSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+sausageSelectionStr
    elif(greenPeppersSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+greenPeppersSelectionStr
    else:
        toppingsList=noToppingsStr
```

Olive selection always comes back as 0 not 1 when it should while checked
`print(olivesSelection)`

Answer (score 2):

1. There was no `myGui.mainloop()` in your program.
2. `TOPPING SELECTION` is not a valid statement. Also, there was no need for the following lines to be an indented block.
3. Don't one-line the creation and placement of your `tkinter` widgets, or else you'll end up with a whole bunch of variables that reference `None` (the value returned by `pack()`).
4. Statements like `olivesSelection=a.get()` are not doing what you think they're doing. That statement calls `a.get()`, gets a returned value of `0` (since it happens on program start), then assigns that `0` to `olivesSelection`. Checking boxes won't change that variable's value. If you want things to occur dynamically as you check boxes, you have to `trace()` those `IntVar`s and add `command`s to the `Checkbutton`s.
5. `checkToppings()` is never called.
6. Checking whether `olivesSelection==1` will always be `False`, since `a.get()` was `0` when it was assigned to `olivesSelection` (see above). Use `a.get()` here.
7. If you use `elif` in `checkToppings()`, it'll only add one topping to the list (the first one that has a checked box).
8. You don't need to use `==1` for a value that will only be `0` or `1` - just say `if pepperoniSelection:`. `1` is a truthy value and `0` is a falsy value (technically `1` is actually `True` and `0` is actually `False` since `bool` is a subclass of `int`).

---

```
from tkinter import *
myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("800x600")
myGui.title("Pete's Pizza Parlour~Order Form")


def checkem():
    print(a.get(), b.get(), c.get(), d.get(), e.get(), f.get(), g.get(), h.get())
    print(checkToppings())

toppings_lbl=Label(myGui,text="Toppings:",font=("Good Times",10),fg="blue")
toppings_lbl.pack()
a=IntVar()
olives_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Olives",variable=a)
olives_chk.pack()
b=IntVar()
tomatoes_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Tomatoes",variable=b)
tomatoes_chk.pack()
c=IntVar()
pepperoni_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Pepperoni",variable=c)
pepperoni_chk.pack()
d=IntVar()
hotPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Hot Peppers",variable=d)
hotPeppers_chk.pack()
e=IntVar()
onions_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Onions",variable=e)
onions_chk.pack()
f=IntVar()
ham_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Ham",variable=f)
ham_chk.pack()
g=IntVar()
sausage_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Sausage",variable=g)
sausage_chk.pack()
h=IntVar()
greenPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Green Peppers",variable=h)
greenPeppers_chk.pack()
thebutton = Button(myGui, text='check', command=checkem)
thebutton.pack()

olivesSelectionStr="olives"
tomatoesSelectionStr="tomatoes"
pepperoniSelectionStr="pepperoni"
hotPeppersSelectionStr="hot peppers"
onionsSelectionStr="onions"
hamSelectionStr="ham"
sausageSelectionStr="sausage"
greenPeppersSelectionStr="green peppers"
noToppingsStr="no toppings."

def checkToppings():
    toppings = [var for val,var in zip((a.get(), b.get(), c.get(), d.get(),
                                        e.get(), f.get(), g.get(), h.get()),
                                       (olivesSelectionStr, tomatoesSelectionStr,
                                        pepperoniSelectionStr, hotPeppersSelectionStr,
                                        onionsSelectionStr, hamSelectionStr,
                                        sausageSelectionStr, greenPeppersSelectionStr))
                if val]
    if not toppings:
        return 'no toppings.'
    elif len(toppings)==1:
        return toppings[0] + '.'
    elif len(toppings)==2:
        return ' and '.join(toppings) + '.'
    else:
        return ', '.join(toppings[:-1]) + ', and ' + toppings[-1] + '.'

myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: First time using this site and i'm new to python and programming in general and this really helped thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a couple of things.

You need to have your `topping.get()` inside of your definition that calls for the toppings. Otherwise you're just executing the `.get()` when you run the program and not on demand

`TOPPING SELECTION` should be commented out as it serves no other purpose

The large `elif` tree is not going to be helpful to you in that as soon as you make one of the `if` statements `True` you're going to exit the `if` block. Also, as a matter of personal preference and code cleanliness, you may want to look up dictionaries for this. Once you get past 3 or 4 `if` statements in a block, they become rather messy.

Also, I know you said that there's more code, but just as a friendly reminder in case you have forgotten at the bottom of the rest of your code, be sure to have your main window instance enter `mainloop()`

```
from tkinter import *
myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("800x600")
myGui.title("Pete's Pizza Parlour~Order Form")

#TOPPING SELECTION
toppings_lbl=Label(myGui,text="Toppings:",font=("Good Times",10),fg="blue").pack()
a=IntVar()
olives_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Olives",variable=a).pack()
b=IntVar()
tomatoes_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Tomatoes",variable=b).pack()
c=IntVar()
pepperoni_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Pepperoni",variable=c).pack()
d=IntVar()
hotPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Hot Peppers",variable=d).pack()
e=IntVar()
onions_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Onions",variable=e).pack()
f=IntVar()
ham_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Ham",variable=f).pack()
g=IntVar()
sausage_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Sausage",variable=g).pack()
h=IntVar()
greenPeppers_chk=Checkbutton(myGui,text="Green Peppers",variable=h).pack()

olivesSelectionStr="olives"
tomatoesSelectionStr="tomatoes"
pepperoniSelectionStr="pepperoni"
hotPeppersSelectionStr="hot peppers"
onionsSelectionStr="onions"
hamSelectionStr="ham"
sausageSelectionStr="sausage"
greenPeppersSelectionStr="green peppers"
noToppingsStr="no toppings."


def checkToppings():
    toppingsList=""
    olivesSelection=a.get()
    tomatoesSelection=b.get()
    pepperoniSelection=c.get()
    hotPeppersSelection=d.get()
    onionsSelection=e.get()
    hamSelection=f.get()
    sausageSelection=g.get()
    greenPeppersSelection=h.get()
    if(olivesSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+olivesSelectionStr
    if(tomatoesSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+tomatoesSelectionStr
    if(pepperoniSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+pepperoniSelectionStr
    if(hotPeppersSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+hotPeppersSelectionStr
    if(onionsSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+onionsSelectionStr
    if(hamSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+hamSelectionStr
    if(sausageSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+sausageSelectionStr
    if(greenPeppersSelection==1):
        toppingsList=toppingsList+greenPeppersSelectionStr
    if toppingsList=="":
        toppingsList=noToppingsStr
    print(toppingsList)

topping_btn = Button(myGui,text='print toppings', command = checkToppings)
topping_btn.pack()
myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: `toppings_lbl=Label(...).pack(...)` doesn't do what you think it does: the variable will be set to `None` because `pack()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

For me (after a lot of reading through posts here and trial-and-error) it was a simple as switching

```
from Tkinter import Tk
....
root = Tk()
....
myvar = IntVar()
mybutton = Checkbutton(root, text="foo", variable=myvar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```

to

```
from Tkinter import Tk
....
root = Tk()
....
myvar = IntVar(root)
mybutton = Checkbutton(root, text="foo", variable=myvar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```